# Records added with "Recordset" not exported to Excel

Tags: export-to-excel, recordset

I've added a new record to a DAO - Recordset created from an existing table, using next code:

```
 Sub insertar(Indicador As String, tolerancia As Boolean, ahora As Date)

 Dim dbsCMDBObs As DAO.Database Dim rstTablaresumen As DAO.Recordset

   Set dbsCMDBObs = CurrentDb 
   Set rstTablaresumen = dbsCMDBObs.OpenRecordset("Tabla Resumen")
   DoCmd.OpenForm "Resumen",  acNormal

   rstTablaresumen.AddNew
   rstTablaresumen("Indicador") = Indicador
   rstTablaresumen("Descripción") = Forms!resumen.Controls("L" & Indicador & "Nombre").Caption
   rstTablaresumen("Tolerancia") = tolerancia
   rstTablaresumen("timestamp") = ahora

   rstTablaresumen.Update
   rstTablaresumen.Close

   DoCmd.OpenForm "Resumen", acDesign

   Set rstTablaresumen = Nothing
   Set dbsCMDBObs = Nothing

 End Sub
```

Next I'm trying to do is export to Excel the table including the newly added record:

```
Sub exportarexcel()
    If Forms("Carga y Resumen").Controls("Exportar").Value = True Then

        DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputTable, "Tabla Resumen", acFormatXLS, , True

    End If
End Sub
```

The export process ends ok and the workbook gets open **but the table doesn't have the added record**, despite of **the table, if queried in Acces, it does shows it**.

Answer (score 0):

Done!! I don't know if it is a fancy solution or it is just "The Solution" but it solves my problem:

```
   ...
   rstTablaresumen.Update
   rstTablaresumen.Close
   dbsCMDBObs.Close ' Just Closing the dbs that contains the rst solves the problem
```